# FragmentTransaction won't Compile in Kotlin Android Project

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragmentmanager

In the process of learning Kotlin with Android, the failure to compile and generally unhelpful error text have left me stumped. The error text says the following:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
>   supplied. add(Fragment!, String!) defined in
>   android.app.FragmentTransaction add(Int, Fragment!) defined in
>   android.app.FragmentTransaction

In both instances the *Fragment!* text is highlighted in red. I am aware that Kotlin refers to Java classes with an !, but I can't seem to understand why it is not happy with the way in which I provided the inputs.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
    fun displayEditRoutine(){

    //Set our variables
    var ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    //Basic "newInstance" constructor to avoid omitting necessary variables
    var frag = EditRoutine.newInstance(mRoutineID,this)

    //Here is where error occurs
    ft.add(R.id.are_container, frag).commit()

}
```

The EditRoutine class being referenced:

```
class EditRoutine : Fragment() {

//Variables
private var mRoutineID: String? = null
private var mListener: OnEditRoutineFragmentListener? = null

//Views
@BindView(R.id.fer_routineName) internal var vRoutine: TextInputEditText? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (arguments != null) {
        mRoutineID = arguments.getString(Keys.b_RoutineID)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_routine, container, false)
    ButterKnife.bind(activity)
    return v
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
fun onButtonPressed(): Unit{
    if (mListener != null && vRoutine!!.text.toString() != "") {
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(Routine.Table.KEY_NAME, vRoutine!!.text.toString())

        //Pass the values into the interface
        mListener!!.onDoneClicked(contentValues)
    }
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnEditRoutineFragmentListener) {
        mListener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnEditRoutineFragmentListener")
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    mListener = null
}

//Internal Methods


//Interface
interface OnEditRoutineFragmentListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    fun onDoneClicked(cv: ContentValues)

}

companion object {

    /**
     * @param routineID = passed ID. If null, don't load content values
     * *
     * @return A new instance of fragment EditRoutine.
     */
    fun newInstance(routineID: String, ctx: Context): EditRoutine {
        val fragment = EditRoutine()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(Keys.b_RoutineID, routineID)
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are creating support fragments you should use supportFragmentManager instead of fragmentManager

Comment: Could you post your `EditRoutine` class?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My min API is 19, so I'm using regular Fragments

Comment: EditRoutine has been added

Comment: did you apply android-kotlin plugin in your build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:
`ft.add(R.id.container_all, frag as Fragment).commit()`

Comment: That worked, I guess Kotlin couldn't see my class's parent

Answer (score 0):

JvmStatic : this annotation is required ([documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/))

companion object {

```
/**
 * @param routineID = passed ID. If null, don't load content values
 * *
 * @return A new instance of fragment EditRoutine.
 */

@JvmStatic 
fun newInstance(routineID: String, ctx: Context): EditRoutine {
    val fragment = EditRoutine()
    val args = Bundle()
    args.putString(Keys.b_RoutineID, routineID)
    fragment.arguments = args
    return fragment
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The answer with casting fragment as `Fragment` didn't help me, it still wont compile.

So I used the advise from BladeCoder and replaced `fragmentManager` with `supportFragmentManager`:

```kotlin
fun displayEditRoutine(){

    //Set our variables
    var ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    //Basic "newInstance" constructor to avoid omitting necessary variables
    var frag = EditRoutine.newInstance(mRoutineID,this)

    //Here is where error occurs
    ft.add(R.id.are_container, frag).commit()

}
```

All thanks to [BladeCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602791/bladecoder)