# Why does platform type doesn't match nonnull object

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in learning kotlin and trying to start a android application project with it.

After I created a project, I got stuck in the first line of code I wrote..

[image: Type mismatch error]

So this is my code and error.

I made MainFragment class extend Fragment and passed it's instance to `beginTransaction().add()` method.

I know that `Fragment!` is a platform type and it is type of Java class instantiated.

But I think there is no reason `Fragment` type doesn't math `Fragment!`.

How do I solve this problem?

+) I also tried `MainFragment() as Fragment` as [FragmentTransaction won't Compile in Kotlin Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507770/fragmenttransaction-wont-compile-in-kotlin-android-project) says, but it didn't work.

+) Also tried `newInstance()` in companion object

Comment: did you imported right fragment type v4? like import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: @YoLo Nope, I didn't, Kotlin was not the problem.. Thank you man!!!!

Comment: Could you provide an answer to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment `MainFragment`,
 use 
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in place of 
`import android.app.Fragment`. and then it should work.